# supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow in iOS9, xcode7

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation

I launch a iPad project base on singleview template in xcode7.
I need the following code in my app:

```
    - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

But when I run the app ,the method above did not work in iOS9, iPad air. How to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the check-boxes as per attached screenshot in-order to enable app orientation. In your case you if you want only landscape mode then you have to check only landscape ones.

[image]

Comment: YES, when I selected all the four, the method "application: supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:" did not work.  But When I select any of these three , the method works well.   I do not know why. And this case happens in iOS9 , iPad air only.

Comment: I am having the same problem with ipad as well